# how to make jqgrid accessible in android if it is bigger than viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, android, mobile, jqgrid

Setting

```
 <meta name = "viewport" content = "width = device-width"/>
```

is used to allow users to use jqgrid without zooming.

If jqgrid width or height is bigger than viewport, jqgrid rows and columns outside it are not accessible in Android.
There are no scrollbars. Tapping up or down is ignored.

How to make parts outside viewport accessible? should tap() event handlers implemented in javascript for jqgrid or other idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set an Overflow to the Container..
(Over Stylesheet you must set **overflow: auto;**...)

If the Container-Content bigger than the Container, a Scrolling will be activated automatically.

Comment: thank you. If I set desktop computer browser window to small size, scrollbars appear automatically. So I think overflow is already set properly. This issue exists only under Android, in desktop browser all is OK.